# IIS URL rewrite path to querystring

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Need some help specifying rewrite rule for:

```
http://example.com/page/my-unique-title
```

to

```
http://example.com/page?id=my-unique-title
```

Note it is web forms app and I am using friendlyurls. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            <rule name="myrule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="page/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="page?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```